# Spring Boot : Unit test hibernate's SequenceStyleGenerator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, mockito, junit5

I have a class which extends `SequenceStyleGenerator` for generating custom primary key for the database.

I'm asked to write test cases for the whole application. While I think that code coverage on SonaqQube can't be 100%, still I'm being asked to write the test cases for the whole application.

I've gone through the source code for `SequenceStyleGenerator` but I'm unable to get it how to test the class.

Here is the code for the same.

```
public class BigIntegerSequenceGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
                                 Object object)  {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
                          ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);

        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
                params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
                params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Here is the test for this file

```
class BigIntegerSequenceGeneratorTest {

    SharedSessionContractImplementor session;
    BigIntegerSequenceGenerator generator;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        generator = new BigIntegerSequenceGenerator();
        session = mock(SharedSessionContractImplementor.class);
        session = mock(Session.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testGenerate() {
        generator.generate(session,new Object());
    }

}
```

I'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:520)
```

I check it by using debug points and this is the code I'm getting.

```
@Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return optimizer.generate( databaseStructure.buildCallback( session ) );
    }
```

`optimizer` and `databaseStructure` are null.

For what I know, when the SpringBoot application runs, it automatically configures the hibernate and the `optimizer` and `databaseStruictore` are configured which will then be used for the models when saving the data.

I know that this will require the database connection mocking but it seems like I'm unable to do it.

NOTE : I'm using JUnit5 for testing

-Thank you